# Does changing /etc/ssh/moduli impact previously generated keys?

Tags: ssh, diffie-hellman, openssh

My company does a lot of automated file transfers over SSH/sftp with banks, etc.  A recent SSH upgrade on a server dropped support for the old/weak `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` key exchange protocol in response to the recent [Logjam](https://weakdh.org/) attack.

Most of the organizations we work with support the `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` and `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` protocols.  However, our `/etc/ssh/moduli` file contains some numbers weaker than what some servers want, so we get periodic connection failures when our server happens to pick a weaker number from the current file.

So now I am looking at generating a new `/etc/ssh/moduli` file and removing the weaker numbers to eliminate the possible failure.  What I want to know is if we can replace the existing `/etc/ssh/moduli` file without impacting our already-generated keys that we have exchanged with others.  I've read some other posts like [Consequences of tampered /etc/ssh/moduli](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41941/consequences-of-tampered-etc-ssh-moduli), but they aren't really clear on this point.

From what I have read, I *think* I am fine to do this since `/etc/ssh/moduli` is used primarily when negotiating an individual SSH connection, but I'd like some other opinions first.

Answer (score 4):

> What I want to know is if we can replace the existing `/etc/ssh/moduli` file without impacting our already-generated keys that we have exchanged with others.

The moduli numbers do not have any connection with *server host keys* nor with *clients authentication keys*. The host keys are used for host verification, the authentication keys are used for client authentication, but *diffie hellman* key exchange is totally different algorithm (ok, not so totally, it is public key cryptography, but it is NOT based on any of the previously mentioned keys [RFC4419](http://www.openssh.com/txt/rfc4419.txt)).

This means that your previously generated keys are not affected.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be fine. `/etc/ssh/moduli` is only used by [sshd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/moduli.5.html):

> The /etc/ssh/moduli file contains the system-wide Diffie-Hellman prime moduli for sshd(8).

`sshd` has nothing to do with client keys that you are using to connect to other machines.